# value is not displayed when enter the value to the text box

Tags: javascript, html

This is works fine when the form does not have any value. But, Once i entered the value on the textbox, it still alert the same messages i.e it is omitting 'You must enter value' for both cases,see at the if else statement. what is the mistake on the below code?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A Basic Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>A Basic Form Example</p>
        <form action="#">
            <p>Name <em>(Required)</em>: <input id="textbox1" name="textname" type="text" /></p>
            <p><input id="submitbutton1" type="submit" /></p>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var item = document.getElementById("textbox1").value.length;
                var item1 = document.forms[0].textname;
                function formValid() {

                    if (item == 0) {
                        alert("You must enter value");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(item1);
                    }
                }

                var formEl = document.getElementById("submitbutton1");
                formEl.addEventListener("click", formValid());

            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In addition to Quentin's answer, you're calling your event handler (`formValid()`) instead of passing it (`formValid`) to `addEventListener()`.

Comment: @Hamidi, i have changed my code from `'formEl.addEventListener("click", formValid());` to `formEl.addEventListener("click", function(){formValid();});`, now, it works, thanks

Comment: You could also simply write `formEl.addEventListener("click", formValid)`, no need for a middleman here.

Comment: @Hamidi, what is the different between `formEl.addEventListener("click", formValid();)` and `formEl.addEventListener("click", formValid)`.  why it is changing its result?

Comment: Because in the first snippet, you're calling the function, then passing the value it returns. In the second snippet, you're passing the function itself, which is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

You are fetching the length of the value when the page loads instead of when the the function runs.

Move

```
var item = document.getElementById("textbox1").value.length
```

inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax in addEventListener  `formEl.addEventListener("click", formValid,false);`
Also replace var `item` inside the function `formValid()`.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/uLC7L/)

Answer (score -1):

```
try this

<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>A Basic Example</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>A Basic Form Example</p>
            <form action="#">
                <p>Name <em>(Required)</em>: <input id="textbox1" name="textname" type="text" /></p>
                <p><input id="submitbutton1" type="submit" /></p>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var item1 = document.forms[0].textname;
                    var formEl = document.getElementById("submitbutton1");
                    function init() {
                         formEl.addEventListener("click", formValid());
                    }
                    function formValid() {
                    var item = document.getElementById("textbox1").value.length;
                        if (item == 0) {
                            alert("You must enter value");
                        }
                        else if {
                            alert(item1);
                        }
                    }


                </script>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```